# [Android] Как передать значения из ListView ?

Tags: android, java

Допустим мне нужно подсчитать пример:

1 + 1 + 1 + ListView

А в ListView список: Собака, кошка, рыба ...

т.е этим значениям нужно передать определенные числа, чтобы их потом подставить в уравнение.

Список в ListView у меня формирует отдельным list.xml файлом

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="260dip"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView android:layout_width="251dp"  //Текст
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/text1"
                  android:textSize="25dip"
                  android:text="This is text1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView android:layout_width="55dip" //Изображение
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:id="@+id/img"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

Вот непосредственно как это выглядит в MainActivity.java

```
package com.pebulator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int Text1, Text2, Text3, res;
    EditText EditText1;
    EditText EditText2;
    EditText EditText3;
    TextView result;
    TextView gorank;
    Button gobtn;

    private ArrayList <HashMap<String, Object>> myBooks; //наш массив объектов, без него никак
    private static final String BOOKKEY = "bookname";    // Главное название, большими буквами
    private static final String PRICEKEY = "bookprice";  // Наименование, то что ниже главного
    private static final String IMGKEY = "iconfromraw";  //Наша будущая картинка

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { //Вход
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);                  //Запускаем main.xml

        //Находим эллементы
        EditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
        EditText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText2);
        EditText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText3);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        gorank = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        gobtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gobtn);

        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);  //определяем наш ListView в main.xml
        myBooks = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();      //создаем массив списков
        HashMap<String, Object> hm;                             //список объектов

        ///С помощью ключевого HashMap добавляем название (то что большими буквами), и описание (маленькими)
        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(BOOKKEY, "Пункт списка1");
        hm.put(IMGKEY, R.drawable.qwe1);
        myBooks.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(BOOKKEY, "Пункт списка2");
        hm.put(IMGKEY,  R.drawable.qwe2);
        myBooks.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(BOOKKEY, "Пункт списка 3");  //Текст
        hm.put(IMGKEY,  R.drawable.qwe3); //Изображение
        myBooks.add(hm);

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,
                myBooks,
                R.layout.list, new String[]{ // массив названий
                BOOKKEY,         //верхний текст
               // PRICEKEY,        //нижний текст
                IMGKEY          //наша картинка
        }, new int[]{    //массив форм
                R.id.text1, //ссылка на объект отображающий текст
               // R.id.text2, //ссылка на объект отображающий текст
                R.id.img}); //добавили ссылку в чем отображать картинки из list.xml

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);                         //говорим программе что бы отображала все объекты
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);  //Даем возможность выбора если есть желание сделать переход на другие формы

        final Button gobtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gobtn);
        gobtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    Text1 = Integer.parseInt(EditText1.getText().toString());
                    Text2 = Integer.parseInt(EditText2.getText().toString());
                    Text3 = Integer.parseInt(EditText3.getText().toString());

                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    Text1 = 0;
                    Text2 = 0;
                    Text3 = 0;
                }

                res = Text1+Text2+Text3;
                result.setText(res + " дня(ей)");
            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: не нужно пытаться "прочитать с listview". У Вас же есть ArrayList, который используется адаптером, вот и используйте данные из него.

Comment: если конечно вы инициализировали свой адаптер коллекцией, а не массивом. в противном случае при изменении(добавлении/удалении) элементов из адаптера, массив останется прежним.